# phpMailer support with one.com

Tags: php, phpmailer

I've recently downloaded the phpMailer script as I was told previously by another Stack user it's a more efficient way of doing such a task.

I've set the mailer up and tested sending an email from a HTML form to my gmail account which all worked fine.

However, I've now tried to apply it to my website which is hosted by [one.com](http://www.one.com) and it doesn't seem to work.

I've looked on the site and got the correct SMTP settings and the correct port number but it doesn't seem to work either.

I'll show some of my code to explain the situation. 
 
**My PHP**

```
require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$firstName = $_POST['firstName']; 
$lastName = $_POST['lastName']; 
$email = $_POST['email']; 
$subject = $_POST['subject']; 
$message = $_POST['message']; 

$mail->isSMTP();                                      
$mail->Host = 'mailout.one.com';  
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               
$mail->Username = 'myemail@one.com';                
$mail->Password = 'mypassword';                           
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            
$mail->Port = 465;                                    
$mail->AddReplyTo($email, $firstName);
$mail->setFrom($email, $firstName);
$mail->addAddress('example@gmail.com', 'the name'); 
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  
$mail->Subject = $_POST['subject'];
$mail->Body    = '<b>From:</b><br> ' . $firstName . ' ' . $lastName . '<br> <br> <b>Message:</b> <br> ' .$message; 
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';
```

After this did not work, I added

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;
```

to try and get an error log to identify the problem, which returned:

> Connection: opening to mailout.one.com:465, timeout=300, options=array ( ) 2016-03-25 14:26:51    SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known (0) 2016-03-25 14:26:51 SMTP connect() failed.

I've got the smtp details from one.com themselves so I'm unsure if the connection is being blocked automatically from their end.

I would appreciate if someone could help me as I've got no idea.

Thanks in advance and please ask if i've lacked information in this question.

Answer (score 2):

As I bothered for quite some time trying to use smtp on a server hosted by one.com the configuration working for me is the following:

```
/*be careful with the one.com servers strict case sensitivity
renaming the file PHPMailerAutoload.php to phpmailerautoload.php could do the trick, but you need to require it in lower case as well:*/
require_once 'phpmailer/phpmailerautoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;  //don't use brackets here!
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
$mail->Host = "send.one.com";
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->Username = "**toChangeTp**your webemail-username"; 
$mail->Password = "**toChangeTp**your webmail-passwort";
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to read [the troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting). It looks like your DNS is failing, so it can't get an IP address to connect to.

You're also using `SMTPSecure = 'tls'` with `Port = 465`; that won't work. Use `Port = 587` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I spent some time on it and according to one.com support this is right solution:

```
$mail =  new PHPMailer;
$mail->Host = 'mailout.one.com';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = '***************';
$mail->Password = '************';
$mail->SMTPSecure = false;
$mail->Port = 25;
```

Comment: Sorry did not work for me, see my own solution with host='send.one.com' instead.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of trying OSX mail to work with SMTP, I have tried to make it work with PHPMailer. My SMTP-Working settings are:

```
$useExceptions = true;
$mail = new PHPMailer( $useExceptions );    
try {
   $mail->isSMTP(); 
   $mail->Host = 'send.one.com';
   $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
   $mail->Username = 'xxx@yyy.zz';  // Replace by your SMTP username
   $mail->Password = 'xxx123489';   // Replace by your SMTP password
   $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                  
   $mail->Port = 587;
   ...
   $mail->setFrom('Your from-address');      // Replace
   $mail->addAddress('Your to-address');     // Replace
   $mail->addReplyTo('Your reply-address');  // Replace
   ...
   $mail->isHTML(true);  
   $mail->Subject = 'Your Subject';
   $mail->Body    = 'Your body';
   $mail->AltBody = 'Your plain text body';
   ...
   $mail->send();
} catch (Exception $e) {
   ...
}
```

Please note that the section 'isSMTP()' until 'Port' is the most important part. The rest of the settings is mentioned to show you what you need to have to make it work.

I have to say, that for me the solution given below with the host = 'mailout.one.com' did not work at all.

Answer (score 0):

This is the unique configuration that works with ONE.COM using PHPmailer. Port 465 is not working but 25 it's ok.

Configuration in phpmailer:

```
$mail->Host = 'send.one.com';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "***";
$mail->Password = "******";
$mail->From = "***";
$mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false; // IMPORTANT!!
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'none'; // IMPORTANT!!
$mail->Port = 25;
```